# How to bound super-critical Galton-Watson & Bellman-Harris branching processes in biological applications like tumor evolution

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process, branching

I have been reading the book by Kimmel and Axelrod, **Branching Processes in Biology** to understand how branching processes are used to study tumor growth and cell mutations in biology.

I have a basic understanding of the Galton-Watson and Bellman-Harris processes and their derivation. From what I remember, the subcritical and critical classes of GW processes basically go to zero over time, while the supercritical class goes to infinity over time. So I was trying to understand how biologists/probabilists adjust or bound the supercritical GW process so that they can obtain more realistic results for the growth and evolution of cell types over time?

That is, I was just trying to understand the mathematical method to bounding these processes in order to derive more realistic or empirically testable hypotheses. If these processes either go to extinction or blow up, then that makes them pretty hard to use.

I imagine that the Kimmel and Axelrod book discuss this somewhere, but I could not find that discussion through all of the formal derivations. If anyone can give me some intuition, that would be helpful. Does the bounding happen in the definition of the
probability generating function for each cell, in the sense that by bounding the probabilities that controls the supercritical phase. Or am I just missing the explanation entirely--which is the more likely case.

Comment: I'm not familar with the details of these processes, but here's a thought. It might be that supercritical processes provide a useful model for a limited period of time. For example, supercritical processes can usefully model the initial spread of diseases such as COVID-19 in a population. So, although they 'blow up' they may still be a useful approximation to reality for a period of time. I've heard of another book on branching processes in biology (by Haccou, Jagers and Vatutin), not sure if that has anything relevant in it.

Comment: @S.Catterall yes thanks for the input. I was wondering about that. Basically the supercritical threshold is when the growth parameter $\mu > 1$. So I was wondering if sitting in regions where the growth parameter is very close to $1$ would give useful dynamics that would last for a reasonable length of time or number of generations of the process. So your comment is helpful. The only other thought I had is that there needs to be some sort of death process or predation process which holds the populations in check.

Comment: But modelling death and predatiion processes seems like it would be complicated given the way that we analyze branching processes through probability generating functions. I have to think about that more, but basically you have coupled differential equations/difference equations for the different species populations. The coupling might create problems for Markovian analysis? I would have to look for some articles on that kind of stuff, but seems interesting.

I will certainly check out the book you referenced. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @S.Catterall actually I just pulled the Haccou, et al., book and it seems really nice. They reference the Kimmel and Axelrod book as well. While Kimmel and Axelrod seem to survey classical branching theory with very rigorous mathematical development, the Haccou book claims to focus on more modern approaches--such as not assuming exponential waiting time lifespans and memoryless-ness. So seems like a really nice book.